# Very few views on my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question ([How can I have Desmos trace a point's path](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159572/how-can-i-have-desmos-trace-a-points-path)) has been getting *very* few views, despite being up for a while. Is there something in it that's turning people away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a small number of questions and contributors around [desmos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desmos) (ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/desmos/topusers) by the other hand the question description is very brief which might cause getting a low score on search engines.

To help your question to get more views:

1. besides the link, add a screenshot / animated gif
2. show what you tried
3. add a brief description of your sear efforts (whenever be possible add links to similar questions) as is suggested in [How to ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
4. contribute to [desmos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desmos) questions / answers posted by others
5. after a week or so, consider to offer a bounty

Reference

- [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Understood. I thought there were a decent number of Desmos posts, my bad.